# Unexpected behaviour of memset()

Tags: c++, cstring

I am initializing array with 99 in all the elememts

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
int main(){
    int a[10];
    memset(a,99,10);
    std::cout<<a[0]<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but the output I am getting is unexpected.

Output:-

> 1667457891

What is the reason behind the abnormal behavior of this memset function.

Answer (score 11):

Firstly, `memset` takes the size in bytes, not number of elements of the array, because it cannot know how big each element is. You need to use `sizeof` to get the size in bytes of the array and give that to `memset` instead:

```
memset(a, 99, sizeof(a));
```

However, in C++, prefer `std::fill` because it is type-safe, more flexible, and can sometimes be more efficient:

```
std::fill(begin(a), end(a), 99);
```

The second and more pressing problem is that `memset` and `fill` have different behaviour in this instance, so you must decide which you want: the `memset` will set each *byte* to 99, whereas `fill` will set each *element* (each `int` in your case) to 99. If you want an array full of integers that equal 99, use `fill` as I showed it. If you want each byte set to 99, I would recommend casting the `int*` to a `char*` and using `fill` on that instead of `memset`, but `memset` will work for that too.

Comment: memset(a,99,sizeof( a)); still there is not change in the output.

Comment: @YSBhai yes, because you're setting bytes. Did you not read the answer? Use `std::fill` if you want each element to be 99.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `memset` is setting each byte to `99` so the first `int` is 0x63636363 which equals 1667457891.  Use `std::fill` instead.

Comment: The hexadecimal number 0x99999999 is -1717986919 in 32 bit decimal. See http://ideone.com/p4Q7Ao

Comment: He passed the decimal number 99, which in hex would be 63.  So the value of the int is 0x63636363, which is 16677891 in decimal.

Comment: That's odd, I could have sworn I copied and pasted that number, but it's missing digits.

Comment: Sorry. I shouldn't be posting when I am feverish.